# FCM Cordova plugin issue. plugin_not_installed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am struggling to get Firebase Cloud messaging working with ionic 5
This is the issue i am getting when running the code below.

[image: Error code]

```js
this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
  console.log('Regeistewring token')
  this.afs.doc(`users/${this.userUid}`).ref.update({ 'tokens.notifications': token 
});
  // backend.registerToken(token);
});
```

I am importing FCM as

```js
private fcm: FCM
```

from

```js
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';
```

I followed the Ionic FCM documentation to install